# including wildcards in pexpect.run()

Tags: python, wildcard, pexpect

my terminal output is

```
 $ setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
   /dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
   /dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
   /dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4 
   /dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

I want the same result from `pexpect.run()`

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> pexpect.run("setserial -g /dev/ttyS1")
'/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3\r\n'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> pexpect.run("setserial -g /dev/ttyS*")
'/dev/ttyS*: No such file or directory\r\n'
```

Is there a way to include "*" in the command ??

Comment: Rather than saying passing wildcard * to setserial...
I simply want to run "setserial -g /dev/ttyS*" using pexpect.run()

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to call `setserial` (over `pexpect`) for any tty? You could perhaps do it like this:

```
import glob
import pexpect
for tty in glob.glob("/dev/ttyS*"):
    pexpect.run("setserial -g %s" % tty)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think found the answer on your question in the [documentation of the spawn-question](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html):

> Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as
>   redirect, pipe, or wild cards (>, |, or *). This is a common mistake.
>   If you want to run a command and pipe it through another command then
>   you must also start a shell. For example::
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > log_list.txt"')
> child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
> ```

Could you give this a try?

```
pexpect.run("/bin/bash setserial -g /dev/ttyS*")
```

Comment: my mistake. What about `pexpect.run('/bin/bash "setserial -g /dev/ttyS*"')`